# Extracting data from buffer C vs Python. Advice?

Tags: python, c, buffer, unions

When I work in C, and I get data on a rxbuffer and it can contain different kind of frames, I usually use a `struct` for each kind of frames, and put them together in a `union`:

```c
buffer: {10 bytes}

struct1: {1 byte, 5 bits, 2 bits, 2 bits,  7 bits, 3 bytes};

struct2: { byte, 3 bits, 3 bits, 2 bits, 2 bytes};

struct3: {1 byte, 4 bits, 4 bits, 6 bits, 2 bits};`

union: {buffer, struct1, struct2, struct3 } myunion;
```

I put the raw data on the buffer, and I get any bit on my union:
`myunion.struct1.field3;`

How can I do it on Python?
Any advice about buffer treatment?

Comment: `import struct`

Comment: You can define essentially identical structures and unions that are accessible from Python code by using the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module. I think it would be less awkward than using the `struct` module.